# How to select Row in QTableView?

Tags: qt, qtableview

I am new to QT, and I'm using `QTableView`, as shown below:

[image]

On the left side of the table, Qt is automatically showing a row number, as I've noted in red. How do I get rid of these numbers?

My other problem is, if I click any cell, only that cell is selected. How can I make it to where, when a user clicks a cell, the entire row is selected, like I noted in pink? For example, if I click the *testApp-copy.itr* cell then the entire third row should be selected.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use

`table->`[`verticalHeader()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5//qtableview.html#verticalHeader)`->`[`hide()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5//qwidget.html#hide)`;`

to get the vertical header and hide it, and

`table->`[`setSelectionBehavior`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5//qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop)`(`[`QAbstractItemView::SelectRows`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5//qabstractitemview.html#SelectionBehavior-enum)`);`

to make `QTableView` only select whole rows.
You may also want to specify the [selection mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5//qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum).

Comment: The documentation makes it look like table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows)  is what you want to select a whole row.

Comment: You can also set these properties in the Designer in case you are using it.

Comment: Hijacking top Google search result: one thing that nobody ever mentions is that your data model needs to return the flag `Qt::ItemIsSelectable` before the table will select anything. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags